# Datos usuario Telegram WebApp / Flask / Python

Tags: python, flask, telegram

Quiero que al abrir la Webapp desde el menu botton, me cargue una pagina distinta dependiendo de quien sea.
Puedo saber quien abre la pagina con el

```
<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
```

en  pero esto solo me funciona en la primer pagina, si voy recorriendo las pagina, pierdo los datos.

Intente con Session de flask, utilizando cookies, que funcionan correctamente si lo visualizo desde el navegador, pero no dentro de telegram, si cargo el script en cada pagina, los datos me salen None

Alguna idea que camino puedo seguir?

Si mi explicacion es complicada, puedo detallar mas, pero no quiero marear con mucho texto XD

Gracias!

este es el codigo de index.html, que es el que muestra los datos correctamente

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    
    <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
    <div class="card text-center">
      <div class="card-header">
        Hola <span class="badge badge-primary"><div id="usercard"></div></span> !
      </div>
      
        <script>
           let tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;   
           tg.expand();
           tg.MainButton.show()
    
           let usercard = document.getElementById("usercard");
    
           let profName = document.createElement('p');
           profName.innerText = `${tg.initDataUnsafe.user.first_name}`;
           usercard.appendChild(profName);
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: La explicación no es complicada, sólo está incompleta. Nos marea el océano de incertidumbre que rodea tu pregunta :P No tenemos la más mínima idea de qué webapp, menú botton, páginas, sessions, cookies estás hablando. Somos fuertes y podemos leer código, así que te sugiero intentar explicarnos con código. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.